# Abrir arquivo (pdf,doc,etc)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Tenho o seguinte código, que funciona perfeito no IE, mas no Chrome não faz nada, na abre o pdf e não realiza o donwload. Alguma configuração especial no Chrome?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="Intranet.Shared.Menu" %>
<dl class="menu">
    <dt><a href="P:\db_intranet\Planejamento\AcordoPLR.pdf"  target="_blank">Acordo PLR</a></dt>
    <dt><a href="P:\db_intranet\comunicacao\correio\CorreioRPR.pdf?" target="_blank">Correio da RPR</a></dt>
    <dt><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Paginas/Sistemas.aspx") %>">Sistemas</a></dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o caminho a partir do local onde a página está e não da raiz.